# how to use ahoy email with api only application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, ahoy

I am using ahoy email in my rails API only application, and I cant able to track the open and click event. Even record is not created in the ahoy table. I don't know how to debug

Answer (score -1, accepted):

from https://github.com/ankane/ahoy

> If your entire Rails app is an API, you can use:

```
Ahoy.api_only = true
```

Comment: Already I have add this line in config/initializer/ahoy_email.rb but it cant work.